# complete bipartite decomposition of a complete graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $K_n$ denote the complete graph of order $n$. Let $G_1 , G_2 , \cdots , G_r$ denote complete bipartite sub-graphs of $K_n$ . Suppose that the graphs $G_1 , G_2 , \cdots , G_r$ are edge disjoint and between them contain all of the edges of $K_n$ . Then we say that $G_1 , G_2 , \cdots , G_r$  form a decomposition of $K_n$.

It is easy to construct decomposition of $K_n$ for which $r = n - 1$ and $G_1 , G_2 , \cdots , G_{n-1}$ is $K_{1,n-1} , K_{1,n-2} , . . . , K_{1,1}$ .

Here $K_{m,n}$ is a complete bipartite sub-graph.

---

I am having confusion in understanding the definition and the example.

Specifically this line ***Suppose that the graphs $G_1 , G_2 , \cdots , G_r$ are edge disjoint and between them contain all of the edges of $K_n$ ***

Comment: What word don't you understand in that line? It is saying that every edge of $K_n$ belongs to one and only one of the graphs $G_1,G_2,\dots,G_r.$

Comment: For example, if $n=4,$ and if the vertices of $K_4$ are $w,x,y,z,$ then $G_1$ could be the graph with edges $wx,xy,wz,$ and $G_2$ the graph with edges $xy,xz,$ and $G_3$ the graph with edge $yz$. All graphs have the same vertex set $\{w,x,y,z\}.$

Comment: By the way, please identify the author and work that you have quoted from in your question, so that the owner of that intellectual property may receive the credit (or blame) that he deserves.

Comment: @bof in the example the first vertex set is always fixed. $G_i = K_{1,n-i}$, how is that possible?

Comment: Sorry, in the example I gave they are not all complete bipartite graphs. So the vertex set of $G_2$ should be $\{x,y,z\}$ and the vertex set of $G_3$ should be $\{y,z\}.$ Is everything OK now?